# How to query that will display the balance deducted from column B to column A in MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I have a table named cdr_records with this columns :

---

```
 TABLE: CDR_RECORDS
 ------------------
 CDR_ID     DATE            CHECK_NO        NAME_OF_PAYEE       CHECKS_ISSUED
 1          2014-01-01      3456111         John Smith          1,830.96                        
 2          2014-01-01      3456112         Chen Lee            90,048.92
 3          2014-01-01      3456113         Hen Lu              22,740.75
```

and I created another table that records all the data for the NCA (Notice of Cash Allocation) receive to be allocated to each check issuances.

---

```
TABLE: NCA
----------
 NCA_DATE       NCA_RECEIVED
 2014-01-01     7,257,000.00    
 2014-01-01     5,564,000.00
```

using the query, SELECT SUM(NCA_RECEIVED) would result 12,821,000

I want to display the BANK_BALANCE of each records of check issuance by subtracting the
 sum of 12,821,000 to each check issuances to obtain the balance as follows:

---

12,821,000 - 1,830 = 12,819,170 
12,819,170 - 90,048.92 = 12,729,121.08 
and so on illustrated below.

```
 
CDR_ID      DATE            CHECK_NO        NAME_OF_PAYEE       CHECKS_ISSUED       BANK_BALANCE
 1          2014-01-01      3456111         John Smith          1,830.96            12,819,170.00           
 2          2014-01-01      3456112         Chen Lee            90,048.92           12,729,121.08           
 3          2014-01-01      3456113         Hen Lu              22,740.75           12,706,380.33
```

---

Can anyone help me how to query to obtain the running balance deducted to each check issuances?
Any help would be great appreciated.. thanks

Thanks for the answer and it really solved on how to display the running balance..

But another problem is that I store the data from different tables with foreign keys as follows :

```
 Table: issue_details
 issue_id (PK)      issue_date      check_no        issue_amount
 1                  2014-01-01      345611          1,500.00
 2                  2014-01-01      345612          21,000.12
```

Table: cdr_records 
 cdr_id (PK)        issue_id (FK)
 1                  1
 2                  2

Table: nca 
 nca_no (PK)        nca_date        nca_received
 111                2014-01-01      7,257,000.00
 112                2014-01-01      5,564,000.00

Im new to sql and Im not good at joining tables when performing calculations. How to perform the same calculation but of relational tables ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with variables.  The key is initializing the total to the value from the `nca table.

```
select r.*,
      (@tot := @tot - checks_issued) as bank_balance
from (select @tot := sum(nca_received) as nca
      from nca
     ) vars cross join
     cdr_records r
order by r.date, r.check_no;
```